# Two GPIO-based TFT screens?

Tags: raspbian, linux, screen

Is it possible to connect two GPIO screens to the Raspberry Pi at once?

Ideally, one with touchscreen capabilities and one without.

If it's not possible, could both a GPIO screen and a small HDMI screen be used instead?

Comment: I don't see why not, if you can work it out amongst the pins.  I haven't done it personally tho.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect more than one display, if you have enough GPIOs. But most screens use SPI and the RPi has only 2 Hardware SPI CS signals.

You can also use the video output or HDMI for the 2nd screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it via i2c interface, if your screen uses one, or if not - you could build a spi to i2c bridge for it.